# Why is PyMongo failing to write to a Mongo replica set when writing from Celery tasks?

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, pymongo

I am working on an application based on Celery/RabbitMQ with Celery tasks writing to Mongo 4.2.2 (using PyMongo 3.9.0). Mongo database is a replica set, everything runs in a Kubernetes cluster. Occasionally, writing to Mongo starts to fail for several inserts (40 to 300 failures), with the odd `ServerSelectionTimeoutError - no primary available for writes`, even though there is no primary election taking place, all secondaries seem to be available. This is pretty much impossible to reproduce while testing, but it happens randomly in Production environments, of course. Outside Celery tasks, it's not happening. I also tried having each task using its own MongoClient instance, same result.
I am using `gevent` for Celery workers:

```
 --pool gevent --concurrency 128 --prefetch-multiplier 64 --without-heartbeat --without-gossip --without-mingle -Ofair
```

The task is basically using MongoClient as a singleton (simplified snippet):

```
   class HttpCallTask(Task):
      def __init__(self):
        self._mongo_client = None
      @property
      def mongo_client(self):
      """Set up a singleton mongo client for this worker."""
         if not self._mongo_client:
            self._mongo_client = new_mongo_client_from_env()
         return self._mongo_client
      
      def run(self, notification, notification_template=None):
         try:
            notification_id = self.mongo_client[DATABASE][COLLECTION].insert_one(notification_template)
```

Mongo client connection is based on some env variables and is using default options, except server selection timeout:

```
mongo_client = MongoClient(
        MONGO_URI,
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10000        
)
```

- is reusing MongoClient instance a bad idea? It seems to improve performance a lot and I have seen the same problem when using a new instance of MongoClient in every task
- is the PyMongo connection pooling configuration relevant for my case?

Comment: Does https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe ring a bell?

Comment: Sure it does, but is sharing a singleton falling in this category? Then, why is it happening if each task instance is using a new MongoClient?

Comment: @AlexBlex btw, using gevent for Celery, so it should not be related to forking

Comment: Good, it wasn't quite clear how you set it up. So check if connection pool is not exhausted and general networking stats - number of file handlers, open sockets etc. The error message might be a bit misleading. It's a generic connection error. The only reason it mentions "primary" is because it is a replica set and all writes go through the primary. So read it as "mongo client could not connect to the cluster within 10 seconds".   Are you using Atlas or self-hosted mongo?

Comment: @AlexBlex self-hosted mongo. You're absolutely right, it took a while to understand this exception is a bit fuzzy.
I am thinking about using `connect=False` and maybe a larger `maxPoolSize` than the default 100, considering tasks are sharing the connection. The most annoying part is not being able to reproduce it in a test environment.

Comment: Makes sense. You have 128 threads and only 100 connections in the pool which leaves room for race conditions. Make pool 150 and see if it helps.

Comment: Since you are self-hosting you can check server logs. Check if there are any anomalies during the times when you have connection timeouts on the client. In particular https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#NETWORK component.